# Default values of uninitialized local variables in C

Tags: c, variables, initialization

Im trying to get my head around declaration and definition of variables in C. My learning material from school says that global uninitialised variables are assigned 0 whereas uninitialised local variables are left unassigned and have a value that was present in that memory address.

However, I tried a following very simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void something(){

    int third;
    int fourth;

    printf("third: %d\n", third);
    printf("fourth: %d\n", fourth);
}

int main(){
    int first;
    int second;

    printf("first: %d\n",first);
    printf("second: %d\n",second);
    something();
    return 0;
}
```

Output is following:

```
first: 382501330
second: 32766
third: 0
fourth: 0
```

Second run:

```
first: 235426258
second: 32766
third: 0
fourth: 0
```

Observations:

- Variable 'first' seems to be assigned a random number every time as expected
- Variable 'second' is assigned the same number (32766) every time, why?
- Why variables 'third' and 'fourth' are assigned to zeros as they are local, not global variables?

Comment: `0` and `235426258` are just as random - there is only one of each among the possible bit patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing uninitialized locals that could have been declared `register`.
That's *undefined* behavior. Your program no longer makes sense.

If you fix it up by sprinkling in some `&` operators (so that the locals no longer can have been declared `register`)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void something(){

    int third;
    int fourth;

    printf("third: %d\n", *&third);
    printf("fourth: %d\n", *&fourth);
}

int main(){
    int first;
    int second;

    printf("first: %d\n", *&first);
    printf("second: %d\n", *&second);
    something();
    return 0;
}
```

then as far as C is concerned the values will be unspecified. What you'll get depends on your environemnt 
and what the main-calling libc-routine left in the stack before it made the call to `main`.

Comment: While I personally agree with your interpretation, compiler authors either have a different one or cannot help writing compilers that have bugs when it comes to treating uninitialized memory as causing unspecified behavior instead of undefined. I wrote this blog post years ago: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/03/13/indeterminate-undefined . The examples in the blog post are no longer compiled to show indeterminate-access-as-UB, but it still only takes a few minutes of fooling around to write an example for a recent compiler: https://godbolt.org/g/NYjb2e

Comment: Thanks for the comment with the links. Worth more than my answer. (Though for a newbie, my answer perhaps could be sufficient. ) Trusting compilers on handling the corner cases of the standard is definitely not something I'd advise after too getting burned a couple of times... Well, at least gcc seems to be doing it right.